# Multidimensional array to one dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I’ve got an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thomas
            [1] => Jansen
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lisa
            [1] => Meier
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gerda
            [1] => Ohm
        )

)
```

What I would like to achieve is an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Jansen, Thomas"
    [1] => "Meier, Lisa"
    [2] => "Ohm, Gerda"
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `extract(array_walk($array, function(&$value) { $value = implode(', ', $value); } ), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'string_');`

Comment: But if you have an array, then it's generally better to work with that array than to set each element as an individual variable

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited my question. Is it possible to make a one dimensional array from the original array like the one I added to my question?

Comment: `array_walk($array, function(&$value) { $value = implode(', ', $value); } );` will convert $array from a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array

Comment: I get a syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION when adding your snippet to my php file. Do I need PHP 5.3 to run the function?

Comment: i edit my answer if you are using a php version lower then ``5.3.0`` where anonymous functions are not implement

Comment: If you're using a version of PHP < 5.3 you really should upgrade now; PHP 5.3 itself is now at end of life and no longer supported

Comment: Without using anonymous functions, then you have to define the function: `function myimplode(&$value) {
 $value = implode(', ', $value);
}

array_walk($array, 'myimplode');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `array_map` and `implode` to get your results

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php

```
$myData = array_map(function($v){
    return implode(', ', array_reverse($v));
}, $array); 

// $myData holds
Array
(
   [0] => "Jansen, Thomas"
   [1] => "Meier, Lisa"
   [2] => "Ohm, Gerda"
)
```

it is better to work with the returned array `$myData = array_map(...` like `foreach` or `$myData[0]` then set each element into   its own variable.

---

Edit after comment

PHP <= 5.3 implementation

```
function getStrings($v)
{
    return implode(',', array_reverse($v));
}
$myData = array_map('getStrings', $array);
```

Comment: ,but OP requires Jansen, Thomas and it'll print Thomas, Jansen!

Comment: @ShaunakShukla thanks for the hint i didn't notice this - i updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$array  = array(.... your array ....);
$array2 = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
   $array2[] = $val[1].', '.$val[0];
}
```

Here is an example: http://codepad.org/qsaQp9sp

You achieve the same result like in *ins0*'s answer, so you can choose what you like more.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arr as $i => $val){
    $arr[$i]="{$val[1]}, {$val[0]}";
}
```